# A question about random vector

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ are independent-identical-distribution continuous random variable(with density function), is there any mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ where $m>n$, denoted as $G(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = (g_1(x_1,\cdots,x_n),\cdots,g_n(x_1,\cdots,x_n))$, such that $G(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ is a continuous random vector?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you call a random variable $X$ continuous if its cumulative distribution function $F$ is continuous. If that is the case, $(X,X)$ is also a continuous random variable, as for all $u,v$,

$$\mathsf{P}\left(X\le u, X\le v\right)=\mathsf{P}\left(X\le \min(u,v)\right)=F(\min(u,v))$$

and both $(u,v)\mapsto \min(u,v)$ and $F$ are continous.

Comment: Sorry, may be I didn't make this question clear. The continuous random variable here means random variable with density function.

Comment: @ZhangQifan - then you mean [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures) (wrt Lebesgue measure). But the same example works: if $X$ has pdf $f$, then $(X,X)$ has pdf $g(u,v)=f(u) 1_{u=v}$.

Comment: Sorry I haven't learnt absolutely continuous.  Could you tell me what $1_{u=v}$ here means?

Comment: @ZhangQifan: $g(u,v)=f(u)$ if $u=v$ and $g(u,v)=0$ otherwise.